# What masters level courses should one take to prepare himself for a future career in the Internet of Things?

Tags: masters, electrical-engineering

I am a graduate student looking to pursue MS in Computer Engineering. I wish to have a future career in the Internet of Things domain. Can someone suggest me the courses I should take that would prepare me for the same?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be about prerequisites of finding a job not related to academia.

Comment: I would suggest that you don't focus so much on IoT in particular. Since you are in Computer Engineering, study programming for embedded devices, and take some courses on practical electronics work. IoT may not (some say it will not) be a hot topic once you graduate. But someone who can write good embedded code and handle a soldering iron will always be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

*Internet of Things (IoT)* is a very large cross-disciplinary domain. Therefore, if you want to become a *well-rounded* IoT professional, I think that you would have to take core classes from essential to IoT disciplines, such as electronics engineering, computer science / engineering, embedded software development, information systems and data science. Obviously, if you want to *focus* your career toward a specific part of IoT spectrum, you would have to study relevant topics at a more detail than the rest (which is still important, firstly, to be well-rounded enough and, secondly, to be ready for potential changes in your professional interests). Reading corresponding [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_Things), which is quite comprehensive, should be a good starting point and provide you with more information on various disciplines and areas of study, relevant to IoT subject domain. Good luck!